# Book recommendation: The Gamma function

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, gamma-function

I don't know if Math Stackexchange is for such questions (probably, I can ask such questions since there is a tag on it) but I want a book on the Gamma function, that is similar to, say,  Titchmarsh's Theory of the Riemann zeta function. I want a book that studies the gamma function in depth. So please recommend a book on the Gamma function that not just lists some properties of the gamma function. I can search Google for it, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest Emil Artin's *The gamma function*, which was republished in 2015 by Dover.